# libvirt/qemu guest VM sometimes needs several tries for DNS resolution

Tags: networking, arch-linux, libvirt, dnsmasq

I'm running libvirt/qemu, with arch host OS and win10 guest OS. For a while I was using the default network configuration, but I started having problems with certain domain names not resolving. I have a work VPN, which has its own private DNS. It was becoming increasingly difficult to get the guest VM to resolve those private DNs, and sometimes others. Sometimes the following would sort things out temporarily

```
virsh net-destroy default && virsh net-start default && systemctl restart libvirtd
```

Other times I'd have to reboot the guest (and possibly the host OS).

After reading the [documentation](https://libvirt.org/formatnetwork.html) I altered my network configuration to this (using `virsh net-edit default`):

```
<network>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>...</uuid>
  <forward mode='nat'/>
  <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='...'/>
  <dns>
    <forwarder addr='8.8.8.8'/>
    <forwarder domain='private.dn' addr='192.168.30.1'/>
  </dns>
  <ip address='192.168.122.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.122.2' end='192.168.122.254'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

All I added was the `<dns>` section...everything else is vanilla auto-generated.

And it mostly works, but frequently I'll have to submit requests multiple times to get it to work. I think it's the DN resolution, because when I've tried a simple `ping` I get a `could not find host` when it doesn't work.

```
C:\Users\user>ping google.com

Pinging google.com [74.125.136.113] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 74.125.136.113: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=106

C:\Users\user>ping yahoo.com
Ping request could not find host yahoo.com. Please check the name and try again.

C:\Users\user>ping yahoo.com

Pinging yahoo.com [74.6.143.26] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 74.6.143.26: bytes=32 time=43ms TTL=51
```

In this example `google.com` resolved the first try, and `yahoo.com` took two tries. Other times it will take 5 or 6 tries before it will resolve.

The syslog looks pretty vanilla to me...nothing being logged when the `could not find host` errors happen:

```
user:~$ journalctl -eu libvirtd
Dec 14 07:50:01 systemd[1]: Started Virtualization daemon.
Dec 14 07:50:02 dnsmasq[641]: started, version 2.86 cachesize 150
Dec 14 07:50:02 dnsmasq[641]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus no-UBus i18n IDN2 DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP conntrack ipset auth cryptohash DNSSEC loop-detect inotify dumpfile
Dec 14 07:50:02 dnsmasq-dhcp[641]: DHCP, IP range 192.168.122.2 -- 192.168.122.254, lease time 1h
Dec 14 07:50:02 dnsmasq-dhcp[641]: DHCP, sockets bound exclusively to interface virbr0
Dec 14 07:50:02 dnsmasq[641]: using nameserver 8.8.8.8#53
Dec 14 07:50:02 dnsmasq[641]: using nameserver 192.168.30.1#53 for domain private.cp
Dec 14 07:50:02 dnsmasq[641]: read /etc/hosts - 17 addresses
Dec 14 07:50:02 dnsmasq[641]: read /var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.addnhosts - 0 addresses
Dec 14 07:50:02 dnsmasq-dhcp[641]: read /var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.hostsfile
Dec 15 08:24:52 dnsmasq-dhcp[641]: DHCPREQUEST(virbr0) 192.168.122.7 52:54:00:e0:55:a8
Dec 15 08:24:52 dnsmasq-dhcp[641]: DHCPACK(virbr0) 192.168.122.7 52:54:00:e0:55:a8 DESKTOP-3GAMEL8
```

Does anyone know why this only works intermittently? Or at least where else I can look for more relevant debugging/logging information? TIA

Comment: Not strictly necessary to solve this problem (see answers below), but I've now completely disabled the built in NAT network, set everything up manually. I documented the whole process in [an arch bbs post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=2009415#p2009415).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why have `libvirt` configured to use 8.8.8.8 as a forwarder when you're already running a DNS server (`dnsmasq`)?

Instead, configure libvirt to use only your local DNS server and then configure your DNS server to use 8.8.8.8 as a forwarder for any requests it can't resolve itself (like your `private.dn` domain) and hasn't cached from a previous forwarded request.  According to the log entry `dnsmasq[641]: using nameserver 8.8.8.8#53`, dnsmasq is already set up to do that, so all you need to do is remove the `<forwarder addr='8.8.8.8'/>` from the `<network>` definition.

BTW, your libvirt network definition says that your private domain is `private.dn`, while dnsmasq says it is `private.cp` - i'm not sure if that's a configuration error, intended config, or a mistake while anonymising your private domain for this question.

You may be triggering some kind of race condition. I'm not sure how libvirt handles multiple forwarder entries in a `<dns>...</dns>` section, whether it tries them sequentially in the order listed, or if it sends the request to both servers simultaneously and uses the first returned result.

Whether doing this fixes the problem or not, it should result in faster DNS resolution overall because dnsmasq will cache the results of any DNS requests it had to forward to 8.8.8.8, so the round-trip delays on repeat requests will be much shorter.

Comment: I don't currently have dnsmasq running globally. My understanding is that libvirt starts a local instance of dnsmasq for each VM, and that the `<dns>` section configures that instance. But I think you're right, the global dnsmasq sounds like the way to go. Thansk!  And yeah, the TLD thing was a mistake in anonymizing data.

Comment: You should also be able to pull embedded libvirt's dnsmasq ip into your vm configuration and use that (given there is connectivity betten your vm and libvirts default dnsmasq).

Comment: Also keep in mind that libvirt is insane abstraction above crazy amount of libs and cli tools and other loads of crap:
+ `kernel` provides interfaces and networking (tuns, taps, vnets, bridges, routing)
+ it's in fact `qemu-system` what actually runs and emulates your vm and guest side of nics
+ libvirt just orchetrates it all together

Comment: Finally even after everything "outside", on the host, is already setup, it still takes some time until vm guest sets it's own internal networking, especially if you are using something like NetworkManager there or other chronic laggards. Check all that those things assembled correctly each time, only then start debugging the issue deeper.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on the very good answer @cas gave, I wanted to give a few particulars. I set up a the `dnsmasq` service, using the following settings in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`:

```
no-resolv
server=/private.dn/192.168.30.1
server=1.1.1.1
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
```

There might be a better way to do this, but I wanted to be able to give `127.0.0.1` as my DNS in NetworkManager, and I figured if `dnsmasq` was reading the `/etc/resolv.conf` that could result in a circular reference.

Once I had this set up, even though I had stopped the libvirtd service port 53 was still showing as in use, by the local copy of dnsmasq started by libvirt. Had to do a `virsh net-destroy default` to stop it.

Then I was able to:

```
systemctl start dnsmasq
systemctl enable dnsmasq
```

---

<s>Next I went into NetworkManager and changed all my connections IPv4 to `DHCP Addresses Only` and gave it the DNS server of `127.0.0.1`. Disconnect and reconnect wifi, test, and all seems good.</s>

EDIT: I've since learned that you can globally set the DNS for all network connections, in `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/dns-servers.conf` with a section like this:

```
[global-dns-domain-*]
servers=127.0.0.1
```

(I'd love to give credit for this, but I can't remember where I got it from.)

---

Oh, one last thing I did while testing: you can add `log-queries` to your `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` and it will add DNS resolution to your syslog. Helped me verify that everything was working.

Comment: As you got so far, don't forget to re-evaluate complete disablement of `systemd-resolved` - if you have it running - it's known to be crappy, it does weird things to `.local` domains and rest of DNS, things that DNS was never supposed to do. Now that you have tightly configured dnsmasq instance running, it might be good idea to divert both host and all the guests DNS traffic through it. It is much easier to control and allows you to bend some stupid DNS "paths" the way you need them. It is a "known instance".